# Splunk Query to search for AWS tag

Tags: splunk

how do I write a splunk query to search if an AWS tag was deleted. I have the index name and the EC2 instance name and the tag name.

Comment: Splunk can't find something that isn't there.  Searching for `index=foo instance=bar tag=baz` probably will return nothing because the tag is deleted.  You would need to search for the AWS event that is generated when a tag is deleted, assuming there is one and you are indexing it.